# Print pattern using nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I want to print the following patterns using nested loop

1)

```
A
BB
CCC
DDDD
EEEEE
ffffff
```

2. 

```
2
44
666
8888
```

```
str='abcdef'
for i in str :
    for j in range(5):
        for a in range (1,j):
            print(i,end='')
    print()
```

this is what i tried.

Result :

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
eeeeee
ffffff
```

Comment: `for n, c in enumerate(str, 1): print(c*n)`

Comment: But don't use `str` as a variable name since it is also the name of the string type.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the logic.

**Analysis**

The line `for j in range(5):` is causing the iteration to go for 5 times for all characters. You need to change this iterate for some sequential counting rather than a constant which in your code is `5`. There are many ways of accomplishing this.

**Altervative ways of doing it**

Solution approaches can be

Using a counter variable to track the frequency of the character and incrementing on processing each character.

```
str='abcdef'
counter = 2

str='abcdef'
for i in str :
    for a in range (1, counter):
        print(i, end='')
    counter += 1
    print()
```

Using enumerate function, you can track the index of the current character and use it to calculate the frequency of repetition.

```
str='abcdef'
for k, i in enumerate(str):
    for a in range (1, k+2):
        print(i,end='')
    print()
```

Another approach, you can use string construction using `*` with integer

```
str='abcdef'
for k, i in enumerate(str):
    print(i * (k+1))
```

Comment: `print(i * (k+1))` instead of  `print(i * (k+2))`